# How to remove a "edit" button on checkout page for the 5 steps

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to know how to remove the Edit button for the 5 steps in the checkout page

Comment: Which theme do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In rwd theme it is in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage.phtml` line 40:

```
<a href="#"><?php echo $this->__('Edit') ?></a>
```

Comment: it's that :), I've searched it before but I didn't found .Thank you